# How to set texture fill-type to 'stack' in excel?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm working on an excel project where I want to fill the bars of a bar chart with a stacked texture. Within the GUI I would select the option 'Stack' and get my desired outcome.

[image]

Now I wanted to do the same thing via C#, so I set the [TextureTile Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.fillformat.texturetile?view=excel-pia):

```
fillFormat.UserTextured("path/to/texture.bmp");
fillFormat.TextureTile = Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

But I ended up with a 'Stretched' texture. Now I tried setting the property to false

```
fillFormat.TextureTile = Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
```

But I ended up with the 'Stack and Scale' mode, which is not what I wanted.

Then I thought,

> Ok, there are 3 options I can choose, and the property I can set
>   is a Mso**TriState**, so I have to provide the third state to select
>   the third option.

But given that [the MsoTriState does in fact only have two members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msotristate?view=office-pia), I cannot see how I would set the texture tiling mode to 'Stack'.

Could someone help?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro when doing this in the Excel UI then checking what properties that uses? That could give you the clue...

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks for the help! Unfortunately I already tried that, and it wasnt useful. If I set my texture to 'Stretch', start to record a macro, click 'Stack' and end the macro, the macro code is empty.

If I record a macro for the whole process of (1) setting the texture and (2) click 'Stack', I get my desired result BUT when executing the macro it inserts the texture and sets the mode to **'Stretch'**, which is neither what I wanted nor what I recorded. It's frustrating...

Comment: The other thing to try would be to create the chart then query the setting of `fillFormat.TextureTile` - what value does that return? Also, I note in the Language Reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.fillformat.texturetile) that it does seem to support more than two values of `msoTriState`, no matter what the information is for `msoTristate` so you might try `msoTriStateMixed`.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks again for your help! When creating a chart with my desired texture-mode ('Stack'), the textureTile-property returns 'msoFalse'. This property as well as all other texture-related properties are exactly the same as they are when I set the mode to 'Stretch'. No difference at all. Applying these properties to a chart sets the mode to 'Stretch'.
If I try the other msoStates, the addin either crashes or the mode is again set to 'Stretch'.